# How To Modify This Array Into Associative Array?

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
$genders = array('Male', 'Female');

foreach ( $genders as $gender ) {
echo '<option' . ( $rowMyBiodata['Gender'] == $gender ? ' selected' : '' ) . '>';
echo $gender;
echo '</option>';
}
```

and that code produce HTML code like this :

```
<option selected>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
```

now, I want to add a value on each option so that output will be like this :

```
<option selected value='M'>Male</option>
<option value='F'>Female</option>
```

I think by changing the array into associative array can solve this problem :

```
$genders = array('M'=>'Male', 'F'=>'Female');
```

but how to get array's index so it can be used as value on the option tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$genders = array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female');

foreach ($genders as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option' . ($rowMyBiodata['Gender'] == $value ? ' selected' : '' ) . ' value="' . $key . '">';
    echo $value;
    echo '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to change your output script to something like this:

```
$genders = array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female');

foreach ( $genders as $gender => $description ) {
    echo '<option value='.$gender.' ' . ( $rowMyBiodata['Gender'] == $description ? ' selected' : '' ) . '>';
    echo $description;
    echo '</option>';
}
```

Note the new use of the foreach params to have a $key => $value pair, then using this in your output

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows,

```
foreach ( $genders as $key=>$gender ) {
  echo '<option value='.$key.' . ( $rowMyBiodata['Gender'] == $gender ? ' selected' : '' ) . '>';
  echo $gender;
  echo '</option>';
```

}